# calling stored procedure is giving an error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The error mysql is throwing is

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

My using phpmyadmin to wreite procedures.

and my stored procedure is

```
BEGIN
DECLARE page_limit int(100);
DECLARE page_no VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE rstarts int(100) DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE rends int(100) DEFAULT 15; 
DECLARE query varchar(255) ;

set query = ' select brandid from brandinfo limit @rstarts,@rends';
PREPARE stmt FROM @query; 
set rstarts =  15;
set rends =1;
EXECUTE stmt using @rstarts,@rends;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Declared variables and variables beginning with @ are two different stories. Read about user defined variables (the ones with @).

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE your_procedure_name()
BEGIN
SET @rstarts = 1;
SET @rends = 15; 

set @query = 'select brandid from brandinfo limit ?, ?';
PREPARE stmt FROM @query; 
EXECUTE stmt using @rstarts, @rends;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Also in your query string you want to use `?` as parameters, not the variable names. And you might miss on setting the delimiter to something different than `;`

Comment: And why? Error messages?

Comment: If you use the procedure exactly as I wrote it, the error is not in the procedure, if the error message really is still the same.

Comment: Post more info. Make it easy for others to help you. Don't make them ask for everything they need.

Comment: i tried your code exactly the same your wrote, it works only if i add @ with user defined variables..

Comment: What does that mean? Where are you adding an @?

Comment: EXECUTE stmt using rstarts, rends; replaced with                EXECUTE stmt using @rstarts, @rends;

Comment: Ah, yes, that changed in a version of MySQL I think. Prepared statements work with user defined variables only. Make sure you assign a value to the variable before you use it. Otherwise it will be NULL. See my updated answer for a corrected version.

Comment: Yeah did that...my error was i have mentioned size for int, and i guess it shouldn't have...ll check it out..Thanks for you help..:-)

Comment: You don't need to add a "size" to integer. It's always the same size. The number in parantheses is a hint for console output how to format it. Nothing more. It's not the same as giving a size to char or varchar datatype.